# Preventing SQL Injection in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-injection

I have this code

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY (db,'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ref = ''"+ Ref +"'' AND bookno = ''"+ Session("number") +"'' ')
```

How would I prevent SQL Injections on this?

**UPDATE**

Here's what i'm trying

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table where ref=@ref", con); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ref", 34);
```

For some reason everything I try and add it doesn't seem to work I keep getting `SQL Command` mentioned below.

The error is this

```
'SqlCommand' is a type and cannot be used as an expression
```

I'm taking over someone else's work so this is all new to me and I would like do things the right way so if anyone can provide any more help on how to make my query above safe from SQL injections then please do.

**UPDATE NO 2**

I added in the code as VasilP said like this

```
Dim dbQuery As [String] = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ref = '" & Tools.SQLSafeString(Ref) & "' AND bookno = '" & Tools.SQLSafeString(Session("number")) & "'"
```

But I get an error `Tools is not declared` do I need to specify a certain namespace for it to work?

**UPDATE**

Has anyone got any ideas on the best of getting my query safe from SQL injection without the errors that i'm experiencing?

**UPDATE**

I now have it so it work without the parameters bit here's my updated source code any idea why it won't add the parameter value?

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server='server1'; user id='w'; password='w'; database='w'; pooling='false'")
   conn.Open()


Dim query As New SqlCommand("Select * from openquery (db, 'Select * from table where investor = @investor ') ", conn)
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@investor", 69836)

dgBookings.DataSource = query.ExecuteReader
dgBookings.DataBind()
```

It works like this

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server='server1'; user id='w'; password='w'; database='w'; pooling='false'")
   conn.Open()


Dim query As New SqlCommand("Select * from openquery (db, 'Select * from table where investor = 69836') ", conn)

dgBookings.DataSource = query.ExecuteReader
dgBookings.DataBind()
```

The error i'm getting is this

```
An error occurred while preparing a query for execution against OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL'.
```

And it's because it isn't replacing the `@investor` with the `69836`

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**

Here is how I solved my problem

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server='h'; user id='w'; password='w'; database='w'; pooling='false'")

conn.Open()

Dim query As New SqlCommand("DECLARE @investor varchar(10), @sql varchar(1000) Select @investor = 69836 select @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(db,''SELECT * FROM table WHERE investor = ''''' + @investor + ''''''')' EXEC(@sql)", conn)

dgBookings.DataSource = query.ExecuteReader
dgBookings.DataBind()
```

Now I can write queries without the worry of SQL injection

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using a [parameterized query](http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/03/parameterized-queries-in-asp-net/)  here is a link http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/03/parameterized-queries-in-asp-net/

Also, do not use OpenQuery... use the this to run the select

```
SELECT * FROM db...table WHERE ref = @ref AND bookno = @bookno
```

---

**More articles describing some of your options:**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314520

[What is the T-SQL syntax to connect to another SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125457/what-is-the-t-sql-syntax-to-connect-to-another-sql-server)

---

**Edited**

Note: Your original question was asking about distributed queries and Linked servers.  This new statement does not reference a distributed query.  I can only assume you are directly connecting to the database now.  Here is an example that should work.
Here is another reference site for using [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table where ref=@ref", con); 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ref", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@ref"] = 34;
```

---

**Edited:**

Ok Jamie taylor I will try to answer your question again.

You are using OpenQuery becuase you are probably using a linked DB

Basically the problem is the OpenQuery Method takes a string you cannot pass a variable as part of the string you sent to OpenQuery.

You can format your query like this instead.  The notation follows servername.databasename.schemaname.tablename.  If you are using a linked server via odbc then omit databasename and schemaname, as illustrated below

```
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("your SQL Connection String")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * db...table where investor = @investor"
    Dim parameter As SqlParameter = cmd.CreateParameter()
    parameter.DbType = SqlDbType.Int
    parameter.ParameterName = "@investor"
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    parameter.Value = 34
```

Comment: I seem to be getting errors when trying to put any of this into my page

Comment: @Jamie Taylor ...going to need a little more detail than "I seem to be getting errors..." in-order to help you out.

Comment: Keep getting `'SqlCommand' is a type and cannot be used as an expression`

Comment: @Jamie Taylor ... I have updated my answer with some corrections to your code and a link to help explain.

Comment: @Jamie Taylor ...I have updated my answer on this question as well

Answer (score 5):

Use parameters instead of concatenating your SQL query.

Assuming your database engine being SQL Server, here's a piece of code which I hope will help.

```
Using connection As SqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connectionString")
    connection.Open()

    Using command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
        string sqlStatement = "select * from table where ref = @ref and bookno = @bookno";
        command.CommandText = sqlStatement
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim refParam As SqlDataParameter = command.CreateParameter()
        refParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        refParam.Name = "@ref"
        refParam.Value = Ref

        Dim booknoParam As SqlDataParameter = command.CreateParameter()
        booknoParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        booknoParam.Name = "@bookno"
        booknoParam.Value = Session("number")

        Try
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteQuery()
            ' Do your reading job here...'
        Finally
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

To sum it all up, avoid SQL statement concatenation at all cost, and use parameterized quesries!

Here is an interesting link that brings you through SQL injection problem resolution on MSDN:

[`How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

use sqlparameters like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table where id=@id", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 34);
```

Comment: I tried this method but it gave me an error `'SqlCommand' is a type and cannot be used as an expression`

Answer (score 2):

you can use parameterized queries.

http://www.functionx.com/aspnet/sqlserver/parameterized.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table where ref=@ref", con); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ref", 34);
```

it does not work because it is written in C#, not VB.

Try something like

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from Table where ref=@ref", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ref", 34)
```

Comment: Thanks I added this but i'm getting a different error now `Could not find server 'System' in sysservers. Execute sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sysservers` any idea what it means?

Comment: You should check you connection string, it is a database error now, not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way is to let Visual Studio handle it all by creating a DAL:
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ.  It parametrizes queries automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) as an alternative (very good way to go if you are building something medium-sized or big). It takes a little time to configure it, but then development becomes VERY fast. You choose from the native, [Linq to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx), OR, try [any other](http://ormbattle.net/) ORM which works with .NET.