# convert an empty string (from textbox) to null using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, textbox, webforms, string

if I don't enter anything in one of the textbox , ASP.NET can't tell an empty textbox and treat it at null... So anyone please help me how to detect an empty textbox and set that to null

i know that this code is ganna work well

```
If MUSIC_TITLE.Text.Trim() = "" Then

MUSIC_TITLE.Text = Nothing

End If
```

but i can't use be couse i have a lot of forms in my application so i need somthing or any function exist in the ASP.NET that can handel this

and thats for the insert in a requet the sql server

```
"insert into Reunion values(" & Convert.ToInt32(ID_Reunion.Text) & ",'" & d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "'," & Convert.ToInt32(ID_Membre.Text) & ",'" & Type_Reunion.Text & "','" & Session("Nom_GIAC") & "')"
```

and tnks

Comment: Why do you want to set it to `Nothing`? It would be returned as `string.Empty` anyway. You cannot differ between `null` and empty in `Text` properties in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you're trying to directly store the textbox values in your database.

Please **don't do this**. If you haven't already, learn about the high risk security threat of **[SQL Injection](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection)** and parameterize your INSERTS and UPDATES.

Before setting the parameters, you can convert empty strings to `Nothing` if required.

```
Dim musicTitle as String = _
    If(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MUSIC_TITLE.Text), Nothing, MUSIC_TITLE.Text)
```

Comment: i know the SQL Injection 
but i already have the controle validation in each controle in the forms

Comment: @Yassineedouiri That is good. And I'm sure you've also considered the possibility of someone modifying the HTTP request or even sending a fake one through fiddler or some other tool that doesn't care about client-side validation. **ALWAYS** validate on the server. And **NEVER** directly send any user input to the database. No matter what client-side validation is in place, it can always be disabled by a malicient user.

Comment: can you please send me any tutoriel that can solve the injection problem be couse i have some textbox used as a string paramétre in my database so i don't need any control validation on it .. so i'm wondring if ter is any method can handlethis mesery :'(

Comment: @Yassineedouiri have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018174/preventing-sql-injection-in-asp-net-vb-net

Comment: tnks my brother for every thing

Comment: String is a reference type, hence it implicitly is nullable. In fact, `Nullable(Of String)` won't even compile, for this very reason.

Comment: @DanielLiuzzi You're right, thanks. I changed the snippet accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In your insert sp should be like:

```
create procedure Insert(@test varchar(50)=NULL)
as
    begin
        update foo set testCol=@test
    end
```

In c#, use below code, when calling the sp and adding the parameters:

```
if(txt.Text!=String.Empty)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@test",SqlDBType.Varchar,20).Value=txt.Text;
}
```