# Insert Query for HTML string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have Sql  database with table name QUESTION.

I want to insert value for QuestionTitle as html string.
Insert query is

```
INSERT INTO 
   QUESTION (QuestionType,QuestionID,QuestionTitle) 
VALUES ("MRQ",
        "QNB5T6TKDMS",
        "<p><span style="font-family: comic sans ms,sans-serif; font-size: 
small;">what was the original concentration of the acid?</span></p>")
```

When I try to execute this query in Sql  it gives an error .
How can I do this so that it will work for html string.

Comment: it give error as:[ near "font": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE

Comment: extra `"` in your 3rd values. try to escape that.

Comment: You might want to check this question : Preventing SQL Injection in ASP.Net VB.Net : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018174/preventing-sql-injection-in-asp-net-vb-net

Comment: is it complusary to replace " with ' in insert statement at time of insert html value

Comment: @pallavi_ios check it once again.I have edited answer.we can use any type of quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have error in using `"` inside the third inserted value

```
INSERT INTO 
   QUESTION (QuestionType,QuestionID,QuestionTitle) 
VALUES ('MRQ',
        'QNB5T6TKDMS',
        '<p><span style="font-family: comic sans ms,sans-serif; font-size: small;">
         what was the original concentration of the acid?</span></p>'
       );
```

You can also use escape slashes

Comment: is it complusary to replace " with ' in insert statement

Comment: Yes.. You have to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try somthiung like this:-

```
INSERT INTO QUESTION (QuestionType,QuestionID,QuestionTitle) VALUES 
('MRQ','QNB5T6TKDMS','<p><span style="font-family: comic sans ms,sans-serif; font-size: 
small;">what was the original concentration of the acid?</span></p>');
```

Hope this helps you.