# Is this query safe from sql inject?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

This code looks fairly parameterized to me. I'm assuming this code is safe from a drop database command. Am I incorrect? Is there a better way to build queries with vb?

```
fname = A
lname = B
name = AB

SQL = "INSERT into [mydb].[db].[Table Name] (FName,LName,Name)"
SQL = SQL & "Values ('" & fname & "','" & lname & "','" & name)

'Execute SQL statement.
dbConn.Execute(SQL)
```

Comment: No, this query is not parametrized and is not safe. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018174/preventing-sql-injection-in-asp-net

Comment: No, this code is not parameterized. What happens if you set `A="1','2','3'); drop database MYDBNAME; --"` ?

Comment: Also, your final paren isn't a string literal and would cause a syntax error. But that's just FYI. Don't fix it. Make the query parameterized as the others have said.

Comment: As long as you're building a query by string concatenation you're practically *always* vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @meetthakkar ADO.Net and ADO are not the same.